# How to add an engine into android project from another project I found in github?

Tags: java, android

I am building a AR application and I need a model engine to render the model. Recently I found a project from github (https://github.com/andresoviedo/android-3D-model-viewer). I want to add its 'engine' library into my own android project.

I am using android studio.

I tried to add engine folder into root and add

```
dependencies {
...
implementation project(':engine') 
...
}
```

in the gradle. But **error** shows:

> Project with path ':engine' could not be found in project ':app'.

Could any one help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
   implementation project(':engine')
```

Assumes that you have another project locally, relatively to your project.

According to the source code of the [repo](https://github.com/andresoviedo/android-3D-model-viewer) there is the main `app` that uses this engine.

In order to import and use the **engine** project in your own apps you have to clone the repository and add the `engine` subproject into your own project. The hierarchy should be the same to use `implementation project(':engine')`, in case you have a different one, you should adjust the path.

[image]

Furthemore, you could compile the `engine` project into an `AAR` library and use at as a single library file.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. You make me understand more and finally I add include ':app', ':engine' in setting.gradle and then everything seems work:D

Comment: @KiMwong you are welcome, glad that this helped you, if your problem is solved please accept my answer